# Can I use bentonite for clarifying beer?

Tags: home-brew

So, I have a 5 liter dark style beer batch which completed the fermentation. It's a bit cloudy at this moment even after racking. I have some pure bentonite clay lying around and I want to use it to clarify the beer.

The questions are..

1) Should I use bentonite to clarify the beer? I would need natural carbonation, as I don't have a keg. Will I need to add yeast again if I use bentonite to clarify? Also, if this is an option; how much bentonite shall I put for 5 liters beer, so much so that the yeast does not drop out?

2) If I can't use bentonite, then can I use gelatin instead? I had a horrible batch  last time I tried to use gelatin. I guess I had put too much and it won't fully sediment.  I had to throw the batch away, as it basically turned into 5 liter jello shot lol. How much (by weight/teaspoon) gelatin should I add for 5 liters of beer?

Comment: I can't give you a super in depth answer as I haven't used bentonite in beer in years. That said, it's totally fine to use and was sold to me by my original Homebrew shop back in the day. You won't need to re-pitch yeast.

Comment: Great, thanks for the confidence!!

Comment: You should ask this at https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This is a duplicate of a question on the Homebrew stack. https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/18724/what-are-the-downsides-of-using-bentonite-for-producing-beer

Comment: Indeed. I am relatively new to home brewing so, please excuse me. :)

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because this is a [duplicate of a question on HomeBrew.SE](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/q/18724/2252) and it is more on-topic over there.

Comment: Sure. Thank you. :)